# Error: Failed to load extension: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado. R

Tags: r

Estoy intentando conectar con la base de datos local en memoria y obtengo un error. He instalado los paquetes correspondientes.

````
install.packages("RSQLite")
install.packages("devtools")

library(DBI)
library(RSQLite)
#library(RPostgreSQL) # Para otra base de datos
library(data.table)
library(devtools)

# Conexión con base de datos local en memoria.
con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:") ```

Error: Failed to load extension: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenia el mismo problema a mis me paso porque no tenia el perfil de administrador en win10 no vale la pena intentar por terminal de comandos sigue saliendo el mismo error entonces lo que hice fue reset al pc con perfil administrador es de la única manera que me dio resultado. si lo solucionaste de otra manera te lo agradecería que me dijeras.